# String em expressão Entity C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net, entity-framework

Estou precisando fazer uma consulta dinâmica parecido com o exemplo abaixo

```
String tabela = "NomeTabela";
Var x = db.("NomeTabela").ToList();
```

Algo assim onde o nome da tabela vai mudar de acordo com a necessidade.

Comment: Em qual cenário precisa que aconteça isso?

Comment: O objetivo é usar algo tipo eval do javascript onde eu possa montar uma string e executar como método...

Comment: Eu vejo isso com muitos problemas, principalmente porque vai trabalhar com reflexão ... eu abandonaria isso ... não é bom, talvez falte contexto pra gente de indicar uma melhor solução.

Comment: Vamos supor que eu guarde um um banco de dados uma serie de expressões em formato string... e queria recuperar essas expressões executando uma a uma... exemplo: linha1: "var registros1 = 100", linha2: "var registro2 = 200" e linha3: "var total = registro1 + registro2"... Não que a soma seja o objetivo.. onde eu poderia registar uma série de outros códigos ou expressões....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No sua classe `DbContext` crie um método, por exemplo, `Set`, que devolve um `DbSet` a partir do nome passado em parâmetro (da sua tabela):

```
public DbSet Set(string name)
{
    // talvez seja necessário adicionar o namespace do seu contexto
    return base.Set(Type.GetType(name));
}
```

Que depois consegue fazer uma *query* dessa forma:

```
using (var db = new YourDataContext())
{
    // Como o DbSet não é genérico, não pode utilizar o código assim:
    // db.Set("Namespace.EntityName").AsQueryable().Where(a=> a.HasSomeValue...
    // As suas queries devem também ser à base de strings
    // Precisa utilizar o package/namespace nuget "System.Linq.Dynamic"
    var results = db.Set("Namespace.EntityName").AsQueryable().Where("SomeProperty > @1 AND SomeThing < @2", aValue, anotherValue);
    // agora consegue iterar a coleção dos objetos resultante
}
```

Resposta dada em **SOen**: [Dynamic table name in Linq](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28099435/dynamic-table-name-in-linq)

Mais informação sobre `System.Linq.Dynamic` [aqui](https://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library).